# Why does Gawk in compatibility mode split records in the same way as when GNU extensions are enabled?

Tags: awk, posix, gnu

I'm not sure if I found a bug in Gawk or if I'm misreading / missing something in `gawk`'s `man` page.

According to `gawk`'s `man` page, when in compatibility mode, if `RS` contains multiple characters, only the first character is treated as the input record separator:

> ***Records***
>   Normally, records are separated by newline characters.  You can control how records are separated by assigning values to the built-in  variable  **`RS`**.   If **`RS`** is any single character, that character separates records.  Otherwise, **`RS`** is a regular expression.  Text in the input that
>   matches this regular expression separates the record.  However, in compatibility mode, only the first character of its string value is  used
>   for separating records.  If **`RS`** is set to the null string, then records are separated by blank lines.  When **`RS`** is set to the null string, the
>   newline character always acts as a field separator, in addition to whatever value **`FS`** may have.

So, when running `gawk -P -- '1' RS="bar" <<<'foobarfoo'`, I would expect the following result (notice that `-P` turns on compatibility mode, per `gawk`'s `man` page):

```
foo
arfoo
```

However, if I run it:

```
% gawk -P -- '1' RS="bar" <<<'foobarfoo' 
foo
foo
```

And the same happens even when turning on compatibility mode explicitly:

```
% gawk -c '1' RS="bar" <<<'foobarfoo'
foo
foo
```

So apparently when in compatibility mode Gawk actually splits records in the same way as when GNU extensions are enabled. What am I missing?

This is on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, Gawk version: `GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the documentation is fairly explicit, I would simply file a bug report.

Comparing with BWK (*one-true-awk* or *original-awk*), it behaves as the documentation implies.  If gawk's developer had some other reference implementation in mind for this detail, it should be documented.

Testing gawk's **`-c`** (compatibility mode), it treats `RS` as described in the question, i.e., differing from the documentation.